# egrep not getting the result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I wrote a small script which will `egrep` two patterns from the server log

```
pattern - 'Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration|Processing PersistenceUnitInfo'
```

Code snippet

```
#/bin/sh
ssh  tomcat@x.x.x.x egrep -e 'Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration|Processing PersistenceUnitInfo' /usr/local/dd/logs/ddservice.log
```

Result of the execution

```
bash: Processing: command not found
grep: to: No such file or directory
grep: resolve: No such file or directory
grep: location: No such file or directory
grep: classpath:db/migration: No such file or directory
```

The fact is there are few keywords belonging to the above pattern. How can i modify the script to get the pattern.

Comment: Do you want to run the `egrep` command on the ssh server, or on your side after the ssh command?

Comment: first i will establish connection to the servers and once established i intend to run the egrep command

Comment: On the server or on your client side?

Comment: on the client side
i am running this script from a  server which we are using for automation  which will establish connection to live servers.so it can be re iterated as client to server

Comment: I am very close to the desired output only thing is to escape the : character i think.please have your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the space using `\` in your searched string.

Try

```
ssh tomcat@x.x.x.x egrep -e 'Unable\ to\ resolve\ location\classpath\:db/migration|Processing\ PersistenceUnitInfo' /usr/local/dd/logs/ddservice.log
```

Comment: Thanks, but do we need to escape colon (:) as well. I  escaped : as well, and got the below output. 
ssh  tomcat@x.x.x.x egrep -e 'Unable\ to\ resolve\ location\  classpath\:\db/migration\|Processing\ PersistenceUnitInfo' /usr/local/dd/logs/ddservice.log

Output
grep: classpath:db/migration|Processing PersistenceUnitInfo: No such file or directory
/usr/local/dd/logs/ddservice.log:21:48:24.083 [main] WARN  o.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration

Comment: i can see the egrep command fetches the result, but confusing is the "No such file or directory " message. Why it is showing,please have your suggestions

Comment: @Arun without '\' escaping the space, `egrep` would treat the following string as the next parameter. For `egrep`, it would treat that parameter as a path to be searched.

Comment: So can the message be ignored ,how can i eliminate the message and get only the desired results.

Comment: @Arun: I tested this answer, the message is no longer there. But in this answer there is a double space after `location\ `. This has to be a single space as in the code you provided.

Comment: @AndreKampling, Yes, you're right. I'm not sure why it would show double space behind 'location'. not able to correct it on SO, it should be no problem after correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I have several assumptions here:

1. I do not see a pipeline before egrep, and
2. Probably "/" symbol should be escaped. This is just for the first sight without having a  laptop under my hand.

Here is workable code:

```
$ ssh username@somehost "egrep -e \"Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration|Processing PersistenceUnitInfo\" /somepath/test.log"
Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration
Processing PersistenceUnitInfo
```

Then:

```
$ cat 1.log 
Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration
Processing PersistenceUnitInfo
```

Comment: This approach worked successfully

ssh username@somehost "egrep -e \"Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration|Processing PersistenceUnitInfo\" /usr/local/dd/logs/dd.log"
21:48:24.083 [main] WARN  o.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration
21:48:24.290 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [